# Change objects properties in an immutable way for specific keys

Tags: javascript, immutability

If the value for pre-defined keys are an empty string, then I'd like to change that to a null value instead.

So:

```js
const foo = {
  first: '',
  second: 'bar',
  third: '',
  fourth: '',
  fifth: '',
}
```

Should be normalised to:

```js
const foo = {
  first: null,
  second: 'bar',
  third: '',
  fourth: null,
  fifth: '',
}
```

Now the following example works:

```js
const normalize = (payload, keys) => {
  const clone = { ...payload }
  Object.entries(payload).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (keys.includes(key) && value === '') {
      clone[key] = null;
    }
  });
  return clone;
}

const foo = {
  first: '',
  second: 'bar',
  third: '',
  fourth: '',
  fifth: '',
}

console.log(normalize(foo, ['first', 'third']));
```

But the 'clone' variable is not that savvy.

Now there is a commonly used method by using [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#:%7E:text=overwrite%20earlier%20ones.-,The%20Object.,copying%20or%20defining%20new%20properties.).

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Do you mean using `Object.assign` to copy the properties of one object to a new object? E.g. `const clone = Object.assign({}, payload)`?

Comment: What do you mean by *"But the 'clone' variable is not that savvy"*? What do you see as drawback/problems with your current approach?

Comment: What does immutability have to do with this?

Comment: The clone seems redundant. It works, but it seems that it's unnecessary code since it's not using the Object assign method. Is that paranoid?

Comment: Immutability is a requirement for the method used. Want to make sure that the solution is not adjusting an existing object.

Comment: `Object.assign` requires you to already have all the properties you want on the new object, meaning you'd need to do the kind of transformation you're doing already. It would be redundant to use it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternate approach looping over the keys argument array. No point in looping over all the keys in the object rather just the required ones

```js
const normalize = (payload, keys) => {
  return keys.reduce((a, k) => {
    (a[k] === '') && (a[k] = null)
    return a;
  }, { ...payload })
}

const foo = {
  first: '',
  second: 'bar',
  third: '',
  fourth: '',
  fifth: '',
}

console.log(normalize(foo, ['first', 'third']));
```

Comment: I like the idea. Could you elaborate a bit on `(a[k] === '') && (a[k] = null)`. My linter is complaining about "no-unused-expression". And isn't the a[k] reassigning the null value? (not immutable, no-param-reassign)

Comment: Same thing as `if(a[k] ===''){ a[k] = null}`. As far as the assignment is no different than your `clone[key] = null;`

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

Refer to your keys in `norm`, return new mapping as
**null** if it's to be **normalized** otherwise the empty string itself.

```
const foo = {
  first: '',
  second: 'bar',
  third: '',
  fourth: '',
  fifth: '',
}, norm = ['third', 'fifth'];

const normalize = (payload, keys) => {
    return keys.reduce((a, k) => a[k] === "" && (a[k] = null) || a, {...payload})
}
```

Output:

```js
const norm = ['third', 'fifth'];
normalize(foo, norm)

{first: "", second: "bar", third: null, fourth: "", fifth: null}
```

Comment: It also needs to check whether the key is in `keys`; only those properties should be normalized.

Comment: OP only wants to replace empty strings if they match keys argument

Answer (score 0):

You can use iterate with `for...in` and check if the key match with `some()`

```js
const foo = {
  first: '',
  second: 'bar',
  third: '',
  fourth: '',
  fifth: '',
}

const normalize = ({...obj}, arr) => {
  for (let key in obj) {
    if(arr.some(k => k === key)) {
      obj[key] = null;
    }
  }

  return obj;
}

console.log(normalize(foo, ['third', 'fifth']));
```

Comment: find() would return the match whereas some() gives a boolean if match exists right?

Comment: yes, but `key` also holds the same result that `find()` would return (in case it finds it)

Comment: Interesting approach. Accepted answer made a good case that looping wouldn't be necessary since the keys are known on forehand.

Answer (score 0):

Why not loop through the array and mutate the object

```js
const foo = {
  first: '',
  second: 'bar',
  third: '',
  fourth: '',
  fifth: '',
}


function normalize(obj, arr) {
const newObj={...obj}
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    newObj[arr[i]] = null;
  }
  return newObj;
}
console.log(normalize(foo, ['first', 'third']));
```